# How to add event handling with custom classes in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I saw a question just like this, but the answer avoids the point with a callback function from the inside of class.

I did a class that reads a directory (ListaDir), make the request to a php server-side and process the answer. I wish to use like this:

```
var Lista:ListaDir = new ListaDir(urltophplibrarythatreadthedirectory); // this is working
Lista.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, myHandlerFunc); // this is the dream

function myHandlerFunc(e){
var Res:Object = e.target.data; // The answer in object containing the list and another info
}
```

Can be done like this? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your custom class extend `EventDispatcher` and dispatch the desired event.

For example, for simple events like `Event.Complete` simply dispatch a new `Event`:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    public class ListaDir extends EventDispatcher
    {
        public function dispatch():void
        {
            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to dispatch an event with data, it may be optimal to create your event classes.

#### CustomEvent class

As an example, this `CustomEvent` demonstrates a `data` payload object:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class CustomEvent extends Event
    {
        public static const COMPLETE:String = "COMPLETE";

        public var data:*;

        public function CustomEvent(type:String, data:*, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false)
        {
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

            if (data)
                this.data = data;
        }
    }
}
```

#### ListaDir class

When this class dispatches your `CustomEvent`, it can send a payload of data:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;

    public class ListaDir extends EventDispatcher
    {
        public function dispatch():void
        {
            var dataObject:Object = {name: "Example Data"};
            dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.COMPLETE, dataObject));
        }
    }
}
```

#### Implementation:

Instantiate and create an event listener:

```
var listaDir:ListaDir = new ListaDir();
listaDir.addEventListener(CustomEvent.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
```

On complete, retrieve your data object:

```
protected function completeHandler(event:CustomEvent):void
{
    var dataObject:* = event.data;
}
```

Comment: Cool! But I'm getting the error "1180: Call to a possibly undefined method dispatchEvent". Is there some library missing to import?

Comment: Make sure your `ListaDir` class extends `EventDispatcher` as in the example(s) above.

Comment: It works!!! Thanks! I think I just did a huge footstep ahed, I'm just starting to understand a few of as3 and object-oriented programming...